# Wicket internationalization

Tags: internationalization, wicket

I have a label which display a given text coming from a String variable.
This variable can have two different values and for each value I have a translated version from english to my native language stored in a property file.

I have the following code:

```
add(new Label("fruit", new PropertyModel(getModelObject(), "fruit.name")));
```

and HTML:

```
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/">
  <div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <wicket:message key="myBasket.fruit"> 
                    </wicket:message>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <span wicket:id="fruit"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

This fruit can be either apple or pear.
In my property file I have a translation for both values:

```
apple=Apfel
pear=Birne
```

When I run my code, the content of my label displays in English.

How can I set the value coming from the property file based on the value of the variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at class StringResourceModel. You should use it as model for your Label. See [user guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_stringresourcemodel).